# How can I create an array assignment from HEREDOC text using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, eval, variable-assignment, heredoc

I have a list of strings I need to convert into an array assignment

eg lets say I have a set of lines like this:

```
   ctools_export_ui_list_form
   masquerade_block_1
   switchtheme_switch_form
   backup_migrate_ui_manual_backup_load_profile_form
   backup_migrate_ui_manual_backup_form
```

I need to create a variable assignment like this:

```
$conf['journal_form_ids'] = array(
   'ctools_export_ui_list_form' => 0,
   'masquerade_block_1' => 0,
   'switchtheme_switch_form' => 0,
   'backup_migrate_ui_manual_backup_load_profile_form' => 0,
   'backup_migrate_ui_manual_backup_form' => 0,
);
```

My idea is to use some HEREDOC syntax:

```
 $str = <<<EOD
 ctools_export_ui_list_form
 masquerade_block_1
 switchtheme_switch_form
 backup_migrate_ui_manual_backup_load_profile_form
 backup_migrate_ui_manual_backup_form
EOD
```

and use that to create the variable assignment text and `eval` it, or some other suitable method.

Are there built in routines to make it elegant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure what HEREDOC  really has to do with anything, here is my commented version:

```
<?php


$foo="ctools_export_ui_list_form
   masquerade_block_1
   switchtheme_switch_form
   backup_migrate_ui_manual_backup_load_profile_form
   backup_migrate_ui_manual_backup_form";

//make the array
$x=explode(PHP_EOL,$foo);
//swap the keys and values
$x=array_flip($x);
//set the value of all to 1
$x = array_fill_keys(array_keys($x), 1);
print_r($x);
```

Comment: The  HEREDOC is for tidiness. I am copying and pasting the lines from a long text list in the PHP block and I want to avoid any formatting errors.

Comment: $foo can be any string structure you like - same result

Comment: To wit, you would use the HEREDOC to establish the value of  `$foo` then the rest still applies. Still though this looks like configuration so what dont you just parse a configuration file like INI or JSON?

Comment: @Dagon Thanks for a neat answer. It saved me a lot of inelegant code to construct a string for an `eval`

Comment: can't imagine where `eval()` would come in to it